# VPN endpoint provider, not anonymizer

Tags: networking, vpn, provider

I am unable to find any VPN endpoint provider, which will give me virtual lan over L2TP, PPTP, or IPsec.

One of this ?types/protocols? i need because of support in my mobile device.

**I want to achieve**

- synchronization of my computer and my mobile device over network even if i am not at home
- playing games with friends over "lan"
- having possibility to get on same network with somebody who is asking me for help so i can RDP/VNC him

I don't want to use Hide My Ass, StrongVPN, HotSpot Shield or similar, because they seems to me as anonynimizers, which will not give me virtual LAN for more VPN clients. Speaking about HMA and StrongVPN i was told i am right by tech support.

**EDIT:** HMA says i could be connected by two devices at once. I'll test it...

LogMeIn Hamachi seems promising, but it seems to me it's working just with their application over their protocol. Let me know, if you know.

Answer (score 0):

You can always have IPSEC VPN at home, along with some dynamic DNS, no need for provider as such.

For that you need a router that supports a custom firmware like [OpenWRT](http://openwrt.org/) or [DD-WRT](http://dd-wrt.com/) at home. I recommend TP-LINK (with 5 gigabit ports, 300Mbps wireless and USB port for 3G fallback....)

IPSEC is called freeswan in language of linux.

Disregard other protocols, they offer no security, especially when you are in a faraway hotel connecting unencrypted and whole neigborhood sniffing your password.

Comment: Can you please expand your answer. It sounds good

Comment: Can you find your mobile device on xda-developers.org or cyanogenmod.com ? Then you have unlimited VPN options.

Comment: I think you are talking about jailbreak/root. That is not the way i want to go. I have iPod touch and i am happy with the system on it. To expansion of your answer: For some time i had my MacBook configured as VPN server, but i don't like i have to care about it, which i think is what i'll get by WRTing my/buyed router